# Nesting files in Nuget package without PowerShell

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package

The title says it all. I have files that I want to nest during the installation of a NuGet package but can't use PowerShell scripts since they won't be run any longer [(see here)](https://blog.nuget.org/20151008/NuGet-3-What-and-Why.html).

Are there any other ways to achieve this goal?

---

**UPDATE:** By nested I mean like `*.resx` and `*.Designer.cs` or `*.xaml` and code-behind files `*.xaml.cs`. I know I can achieve that by adding a `<DependentUpon>` element in the *.csproj file but I don't know how I can add that element without using PowerShell.

[image: Screenshot of nested files in solution explorer]

---

**UPDATE2:** [init.ps1 runs the first time a package is installed in a solution](https://everydaylifein.net/netframework/running-powershell-scripts-during-nuget-package-installation-and-removal.html). That won't cut it though. I would need the script to run when the package is installed into a project just like `install.ps1` was run up to NuGet3.

---

**UPDATE3:** What I want to do is to add 3 files into the `Properties` folder of the target projects (`Resources.resx`, `Resources.tt` and `Resources.Designer.cs`). They are a replacement for the usual resources implementation. These files are installed by the nuget package when it is added to the project.

This is the part of the `*.nuspec` file that adds them to the `Content` folder of the package. As only one of them is actually content (the others being an Embedded Resource and Compile respectively) it would be nice to be able to set their build actions accordingly but one step at a time.

```
<files>
  <file src="Properties\Resources.resx" target="content\Properties\Resources.resx" />
  <file src="Properties\Resources.tt.pp" target="content\Properties\Resources.tt.pp" />
  <file src="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs" target="content\Properties\Resources.Designer.cs" />
</files>
```

As these files are added to the projects I want the nesting inside the `*.csproj` file and not happen via a separate `*.props` file if that is somehow possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "nest files"? creating a tree structure in your nupkg?

Comment: @MartinUllrich please see my update

Comment: `Powershell script support was modified to no longer execute install and uninstall scripts, but init scripts are still executed` <- _some_ scripts won't run any more... but others will!

Comment: @gvee [Init.ps1 runs the first time a package is installed in a solution](https://everydaylifein.net/netframework/running-powershell-scripts-during-nuget-package-installation-and-removal.html). That won't cut it though. I need the script to run when the package is installed into a project.

Comment: Do you actually need a script to lay out the files, or simply to lay out your nuget content up front so it's installed as-is in the proper directories?  We use .nuproj entries with `<itemgroup><file include=...><targetpath>TopDir\NesteDir\...</targetpath>...`

Comment: @MatthewWetmore I updated my question. Can NuProj do that?

Comment: @SebastianWeber - you can explicitly have a target directory in the .nuproj as I gave the example.  The "..." isn't a keyword, but just "your info goes here"

Answer (score 1):

Packages can add MSBuild items like this to a project by using a .props file in the package.  It would contain the same content that you would put into the .csproj file.

The down side of this is that the content cannot be modified by the user. If you need to modify the user's actual project file and copy content to the project folder you would have to include a .targets file in your package and set BeforeTargets="Build" on your target. This would give you a chance to run before build and make changes as needed.

The build folder works for both packages.config and PackageReference (NETCore SDK) projects. You can find more out about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#including-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package

Comment: The `*.props` file isn't a solution as a least one of the installed files needs to be editable. A `*.targets`file wouldn't really help as the only thing it could do would be to call the powershell script which is something I want to avoid if possible. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: The props/targets file gives you an opportunity to execute your own scripts and make the needed changes.NuGet does not provide a built in way to copy content to the project or to run a script on install/uninstall since that concept does not exist for PackageReference projects where the dependency graph is calculated independently for each Restore.

Comment: It's not 100% what I want to be honest. I want to get away from PowerShell not call PowerShell from a custom target. But it got the job done and it would be a shame to let the bounty go to waste a second time.